# Running vpn on access point

Tags: vpn

just a question I need help with.
Long story short, I have 4gee router as no other Internet available in my area.
Our son plays xbox and has a wired access point in his room but xbox doesnt like cgnat and he kept getting kicked all the time and nat type was strict.
I installed nordvpn on laptop and connect to access point and then connected via ethernet to xbox.
Now xbox works fine via the fixed ip of the vpn.

My question is,
If I get a vpn client router and set up nordvpn on that and use in access point mode to replace his current wired access point will the vpn still work?

Hope this makes some sense

Thanks